# upgraded to 6gb of ram only 3.5 showing

Tags: upgrade, ram

k so i had 4gb of ram only 3.5 was usable i upgraded to 6 and only 3.5 are still usuable ive installed the pae kernal after i restarted it amde me reinstall it and it yet didnt recognize the ram

```
flags       : pae fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm tpr_shadow
flags       : pae fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm tpr_shadow
```

eugen@LINUX:~$ 
 and it does show the ram but it doesnt recognize it in systym monitor and i cant use it

```
  PCI (sysfs)  
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A11
       date: 11/30/2006
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 448KiB
       capabilities: pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppytoshiba int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb ls120boot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 700
       size: 16KiB
       capacity: 16KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 701
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1000
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 6GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: 6400EL Series
          vendor: 7F7F7F7F7F020000
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_1
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: KC6844-ELG37
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: B01EBFEE
          slot: DIMM_3
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: 6400EL Series
          vendor: 7F7F7F7F7F020000
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_2
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
          product: KC6844-ELG37
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: B01EC9EE
          slot: DIMM_4
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
```

Update:
It is a Dell Optiplex gx620 low profile- the CPU and 2GB of the RAM is stock, I got an extra 4GB of RAM, new 500GB hard drive and a dedicated graphics in it.

Comment: What's your reason for using PAE rather than 64-bit?  Which kernel did you install?  AFAIK there's no need for a separate kernel for PAE after Ubuntu 12.10.  Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: can my processer handle 32 bit its and old computer and the old hard drive i had in it had 32 bit windows so i assumed i coudlnt run 64 bit

Comment: What computer is it?  Could you give more details?  CPU type, version of Ubuntu, etc.

Most computers made in the last 10 years are 64-bit capable.

Comment: not xactly sure its a dell optiplex origanally 2gb ram -ddr 2 250 gb hard drive has a 3.2 gz dual core  ill see if i can find out i kinda lost the cover

Comment: it is a dell optiplex gx620 low profile the cpu and 2gb of the ram is stock i got an extra 4 gb of ram new 500 gb hard drive and a dedicated draphics in it

Comment: Your CPU can run 64 bit OS (you can see this by the lm flag). lm means long mode CPU in this case (64bit)

Comment: Use the command `free` to show available ram

Comment: What tool are you using to show the amount of RAM?  Where are you seeing that it's 3.5GB or 3.4GB?

Comment: i am using systym monitor and also if i click on the top right and go into about computer it also says i got 3.4 GiB assume thats  same as gb

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, your CPU is 64-bit.

While I don't know why the extra RAM isn't currently showing under PAE, my recommendation is nevertheless to run a 64-bit build of Ubuntu on it.

- While PAE allows the system to make use of additional RAM, any given application is still limited to 3GB.  Using 64-bit Ubuntu overcomes this.
- Software compiled for 64-bit benefits from a number of optimisations that software compiled for x86 doesn't, improving performance in some areas.  For example, databases run significantly faster.
- Some software is slightly larger when compiled for 64-bit due to its use of 64-bit pointers, but the additional performance and the ability to have large amounts of RAM installed (over 3GB per application, or over ~3.5GB total) overcome this.

Comment: ok so bad new i upgraded to 64 bit i did a clean reinstall and for soem reason its only coming up wioth 3.4 gb of ram

Comment: `Linux LINUX-OptiPlex-GX620 3.19.0-26-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 12 14:09:17 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`